# Namespace issue in xslt

Tags: xslt

I am trying to convert following xml into other xml but I am not getting the values for xCoordinate and yCoordinate. I would like to convert the structure from source - XML to Target-XML where the goocodes will match and the result would be assigned to x and y.

Source - XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AddressResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" errorCode="0" errorDescription="">
  <wrappedResultList xmlns="http://xlocate.xserver.ptvag.com">
    <ResultAddress city="Amsterdam" city2="" country="NL" houseNumber="" postCode="1***" state="Noord-Holland" street="" adminRegion="Amsterdam" appendix="" classificationDescription="EXACT" countryCapital="Amsterdam" detailLevelDescription="CITY" totalScore="100">
      <wrappedAdditionalFields />
      <coordinates>
        <kml xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://common.xserver.ptvag.com" />
        <point x="4.89327999999999" y="52.373090000000005" xmlns="http://common.xserver.ptvag.com" />
      </coordinates>
    </ResultAddress>
    <ResultAddress city="Amsterdam-Zuidoost" city2="" country="NL" houseNumber="" postCode="110*" state="Noord-Holland" street="" adminRegion="Amsterdam" appendix="" classificationDescription="EXACT" countryCapital="Amsterdam" detailLevelDescription="CITY" totalScore="80">
      <wrappedAdditionalFields />
      <coordinates>
        <kml xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://common.xserver.ptvag.com" />
        <point x="4.9513699999999838" y="52.316199999999988" xmlns="http://common.xserver.ptvag.com" />
      </coordinates>
    </ResultAddress>
    <ResultAddress city="Nieuw-Amsterdam" city2="" country="NL" houseNumber="" postCode="7833" state="Drenthe" street="" adminRegion="Emmen" appendix="" classificationDescription="EXACT" countryCapital="Amsterdam" detailLevelDescription="CITY" totalScore="80">
      <wrappedAdditionalFields />
      <coordinates>
        <kml xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://common.xserver.ptvag.com" />
        <point x="6.8528699999999994" y="52.716139999999982" xmlns="http://common.xserver.ptvag.com" />
      </coordinates>
    </ResultAddress>
  </wrappedResultList>
</AddressResponse>
```

Target - XML

```
<GeoCodeResponse>
<geocordinate>
<xCordinate>4.89327999999999</xCordinate>
<yCordinate>52.716139999999982</yCordinate>
</geocordinate>
</GeoCodeResponse>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xl="http://xlocate.xserver.ptvag.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cm="http://common.xserver.ptvag.com" exclude-result-prefixes="xl xsi xsd cm" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

    <GeoCodeResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <geocordinate xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:for-each select="AddressResponse/xl:wrappedResultList/xl:ResultAddress">
 <xsl:sort select="@xl:totalScore" order="descending" data-type="number"/>

<xsl:if test="position()= 1">
<xCordinate> <xsl:value-of select="/xl:coordinates/cm:point/cm:x" /></xCordinate>

<yCordinate>  <xsl:value-of select="/xl:coordinates/cm:point/cm:y" /></yCordinate>
</xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
  </geocordinate>    
    </GeoCodeResponse>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help what could be done in above xslt.

Comment: Note that you have conflicting namespace declarations for xsi and xsd in the stylesheet header and in the GeoCodeResponse element (the ones in the header are incorrect). This is an error, though it may not be a fatal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. The coordinates are attributes, not nodes.

change it into this:

```
<xsl:if test="position()= 1">
    <xCordinate>
        <xsl:value-of select="xl:coordinates/cm:point/@x" />
    </xCordinate>
    <yCordinate>
        <xsl:value-of select="xl:coordinates/cm:point/@y" />
    </yCordinate>
</xsl:if>
```

You are also referencing the coordinates node from the root, but it should be relative. I changed `/xl:coordinaties` into `xl:coordinates`

Comment: "*I changed /xl:coordinaties into ./xl:coordinates*" You can remove the `./` part.

Comment: Thank you very much for very quick reply.

Comment: @michael.hor257k you're right. even though it's technically the same, that makes it even more clear probably

Comment: @user3747335 did this work out OK for you? If so, please consider marking this as the correct answer...